# (Visual C++) Loading JPG resources

Tags: c++, resources, jpeg

I've added a section called JPG with a image whose ID is a constant named LOGO.
For loading it, I've tried to create a CBitmap like this:
CBitmap resource;
resource.LoadBitmapW(LOGO);
Although it fails badly (returns zero and for some reason GetLastError() doesn't get filled with an error code).
How can I load the JPG images from resources to (hopefully) get an HBITMAP so that I can load it into a CStatic frame?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, LoadBitmap can only load BMP files, not JPEG. You can try storing your logo in bitmap format and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, it's a way yeah, but I'd prefer to have it in JPEG/JPG/PNG because of file size, I've been told to scout for GDI/GDI+, any ideas?

Comment: I think GDI+ can load more file formats. Another option is to include [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) in your project, it's open source and pretty easy to use. As an aside, if you're just starting out, I wouldn't pick MFC as my GUI framework of choice. An OK idea in 2002, but by now there must be better alternatives.

Comment: Thing is I want to provide my exacutable as-is without DLLs or a bloated binary.. With that kind-of-in-mind, what would you recommend?